# Detect paragraph in a form

Tags: php

How can I detect that there is different paragraphs in a form? In this example if the user writes different paragraphs, the echo puts all toguether. I tried white-space:pre and it did not work. I do not know what else can I do to echo the text with `<p>`?

CSS:

```
#text {  
    white-space:pre;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action='normal-html.php' method='post'> 
<textarea id="text" name='text' rows='15' cols='60'></textarea> <br/> 
<input type='submit' value='Convertir a html' /> 
</form> 

<br />

<?php
$text = $_POST[text];
echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at `nl2br()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a job for http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

```
string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )

Returns string with '<br />' or '<br>' inserted before all 
newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).
```

You can use this as you echo out the data, so that way you are never changing what is in the database - or you can simply alter the user input as you save it to the database. Personally I am a fan of the first option, but whatever works best for your application.

Edit: If you want to use only `<p>` tags, you could also do this using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$text = '<p>';
$text.= str_replace('\n', '</p><p>', $_POST[text]);
```

The `\n` is generally a new line, depending on how it is read, you may need to use `\r\n` and the string replace will do the rest. This will leave a spare `<p>` on the end of the string, but you see where this is going.

Comment: This is interesting and useful. Thank you!. But I am asking to echo the text with the <p> </p> tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **explode** function ([php manual page](https://www.php.net/explode)):

```
$your_array = explode("\n", $your_string_from_db);
```

Example:

```
$str = "Lorem Ipsum\nAlle jacta est2\nblblbalbalbal";
$arr = explode("\n", $str);

foreach ( $arr as $item){
   echo "<p>".$item."</p>";
}
```

Output:

```
 Lorem Ipsum
 Alle jacta est 
 blblbalbalbal
```

Comment: To display this, you will still need to echo out all the individual elements of the array - and the browser will happily hide all the line breaks as whitespace - unless you specifically add a manual `<br>` to the end of each element.

Comment: You're right. You receive an array back and should do a foreach loop and append the right tags. I will edit my answer to perfect it

Comment: This is quite close but it has the problem that it will not reflect if there is one line break or two. I mean if there is for example an address o poetry with one line break, it will convert in p too